# Safe way of casting void* to something higher?

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I've got a generic class that manages resources of all kinds of types, but since I don't want to create an instance of ResourceManager for every T there is (thus having one resource manager for each type T), I have to make the type of T unknown to the ResourceManager class.

I do this by saving a map of void* pointers and converting them back to the required format if someone requests a certain type out of a templated Load() method;

```
template <typename T>
T* Load(const std::string &location)
{
    //do some stuff here

    //everybody take cover!!!
    return static_cast<T*>(m_resources[location]);
}
```

I use template specialization to introduce different Loaders to the class:

```
template<>
AwesomeType* Load(const std::string &location)
{
    //etc.

    return static_cast<AwesomeType*>(m_resources[location]);
}
```

I am aware that this is ugly, but there is no way around it right now. I could introduce static maps in the inside of the specialized Load methods, but that way I can't bind the lifetime of the resources to the lifetime of an ResourceManager object, which is an essential feature.

But since this is somewhat dangerous (since those void* pointers can be anything), I'd like to at least check at runtime if the conversion is going to work, so I can react to it without having the application crash.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use a `dynamic_cast` and check for `NULL`?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` converts a known type to another known type if possible. `void*` is not a known type, but a no-type. The compiler won't let you do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily do this, if you extend your saved value type - make it a struct that also saves a `type_info` object:

```
#include <type_info>

struct ResourceInfo
{
  std::type_info const& info;
  void* ptr;
};

// ...

// just to give you the general idea
template<class Res>
void CacheResource(std::string const& location, Res* res)
{
  ResourceInfo ri = { typeid(Res), res };
  m_resources.insert(std::make_pair(location, ri));
}

template<class Res>
Res* Load(std::string const& location)
{
  map_type::const_iterator res_it = m_resources.find(location);
  if(res_it != m_resources.end())
  {
    if(typeid(Res) != res_it->second.info)
    {
      throw SorryBuddyWrongResourceType(some_info_here);
    }
    return static_cast<Res*>(res_it->second.ptr);
  }
}
```

This is similar to how I do it, but I use a `shared_ptr<void>` to save the resources.

Comment: @heishe: Remember though, that this doesn't allow basic covariance between resource types, the exact same type must be used for the template for caching (preloading, whatever) and on every load, else this will fail.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to check what you can cast `void*` to, unless you store additional information that indicates the actual type with each pointer.

A more "C++ way" to do what you want is to derive each resource class from an abstract base class `Resource`, and store a map of pointers to `Resource` in your resource manager. Then you can use `dynamic_cast<T*>` to convert to the required type, and this will return `NULL` if the pointer is to an object of the wrong type. Or (depending on what you want to do) you can simply return a `Resource*` pointer and use virtual functions to implement the functionality of each resource.

Comment: + since this answer is also very helpful, but Xeo's answer expands a little bit more so I'll accept his answer. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 5):

<sup>(I'm sure this is already answered by many other questions about void pointers, but here we go ...)</sup>

> But since this is somewhat dangerous
>   (since those void* pointers can be
>   anything), I'd like to at least check
>   at runtime if the conversion is going
>   to work, so I can react to it without
>   having the application crash.

You cannot check. This is the thing about void* pointers. You don't have a clue what they are pointing to, and you cannot (are not allowed to) inspect the memory they point to without knowing its type.

If you have a `void*` you simply must know beforehand what it is really pointing to and then cast appropriately.